# Alignment of captions in minipage

Tags: floats, captions, minipage

**SOLUTION:** By changing the caption setup and including "raggedright" I was able to solve the problem

```
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=false, justification=raggedright, skip=5pt}
```

---

I have a bunch of graphs, but I have some problems with the alignment of the captions and all the others post about this doesn't solve the problem. I want a vertical alignment so that the captions starts at the same place (see picture) for all graphs, but how?

Short code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf, skip=5pt} %default=10pt

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t][H]
    \hspace*{-2cm} 
    \begin{minipage}{8.25cm} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
        \caption{Longevity - Minimum Variance}    
        \label{LongGraph5} 
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
        \caption{Longevity - Tangency Portfolio}    
        \label{LongGraph6} 
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \hspace*{-2cm} 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm}   
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \caption{Longevity - Sortino}   
        \label{LongGraph7}  
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
        \caption{Longevity - Risk Longevity}   
        \label{LongGraph8}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Minimal Working Example:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \usepackage{mwe}

    \captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf, skip=5pt} %default=10pt

    \begin{document} 

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \hspace*{-2cm} 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm} 
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1} 
        \caption{Longevity - Minimum Variance}    
        \label{LongGraph5} 
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm} 
    \includegraphics{example-image-1x1}
        \caption{Longevity - Tangency Portfolio}    
        \label{LongGraph6} 
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \hspace*{-2cm} 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm}
        \includegraphics{example-image-1x1}
        \caption{Longevity - Sortino}   
        \label{LongGraph7}  
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm} 
        \includegraphics{example-image-1x1}
        \caption{Longevity - Risk Longevity}   
        \label{LongGraph8} 
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Code including the graphs

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf, skip=5pt} %default=10pt

    %Color definitions
    \definecolor{green}{RGB}{0, 102, 0}
    \definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{0, 125, 255}
    \definecolor{blue2}{RGB}{0, 102, 204}
    \definecolor{blue3}{RGB}{0, 76, 153}
    \definecolor{blue4}{RGB}{0, 51, 102}

    \begin{document}
    \section{Bonus Potential - Side by Side}
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \hspace*{-2cm} 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Bonus Potential (bn)},
        ylabel={Frequency},     
        xmin=0, xmax=600,
        ymin=0, ymax=80,
        xtick={0,100, 200,300,400,500,600},
        ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
        xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,      
        legend pos=north west,
        legend style={font=\tiny}]
        \legend{-20\%, -10\%, 0\%*, +10\%, +20\%},
        \addplot[color=blue1, style={line width=0.7pt},smooth]
        coordinates {
        (120,0)
        (180,0)
        (240,39)
        (300,55)
        (360,6)
        (420,0)
        };       
        \addplot[color=blue2,style={line width=0.8pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (120,0)
        (180,1)
        (240,30)
        (300,59)
        (360,9)
        (420,1)
        (480,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=green,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (120,0)
        (180,5.8)
        (240,59.8)
        (300,34.2)
        (360,0.2)
        (420,0)
        };  
        \addplot[color=blue3,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (120,0)
        (180,1)
        (240,31)
        (300,62)
        (360,6)
        (420,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=blue4,style={line width=1pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (120,0)
        (180,1)
        (240,34)
        (300,52)
        (360,13)
        (420,0)
        };        
        \end{axis}  
        \end{tikzpicture}   
        \caption{Longevity - Minimum Variance}    
        \label{LongGraph5} 
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Bonus Potential (bn)},
        ylabel={Frequency},     
        xmin=0, xmax=600,
        ymin=0, ymax=80,
        xtick={0,100, 200,300,400,500,600},
        ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
        xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,      
        legend pos=north west,
        legend style={font=\tiny}]
        \legend{-20\%, -10\%, 0\%*, +10\%, +20\%},
        \addplot[color=blue1, style={line width=0.7pt},smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,4)
        (300,35)
        (360,51)
        (420,10)
        (480,0)
        };       
        \addplot[color=blue2,style={line width=0.8pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,1)
        (300,31)
        (360,49)
        (420,18)
        (480,1)
        (540,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=green,style={line width=1pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,10.5)
        (300,56.4)
        (360,32.5)
        (420,0.6)
        (480,0)
        };  
        \addplot[color=blue3,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,31)
        (300,53)
        (360,16)
        (420,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=blue4,style={line width=1pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,1)
        (300,33)
        (360,43)
        (420,23)
        (480,0)
        };        
        \end{axis}  
        \end{tikzpicture}   
        \caption{Longevity - Tangency Portfolio}    
        \label{LongGraph6} 
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[H]
    \hspace*{-2cm} 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Bonus Potential (bn)},
        ylabel={Frequency},     
        xmin=0, xmax=600,
        ymin=0, ymax=80,
        xtick={0,100, 200,300,400,500,600},
        ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
        xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,      
        legend pos=north west,
        legend style={font=\tiny}]
        \legend{-20\%, -10\%, 0\%*, +10\%, +20\%},
        \addplot[color=blue1, style={line width=0.7pt},smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,31)
        (300,53)
        (360,16)
        (420,0)
        };       
        \addplot[color=blue2,style={line width=0.8pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,37)
        (300,45)
        (360,17)
        (420,1)
        (480,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=green,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (120,0)
        (180,3.3)
        (240,50)
        (300,46.3)
        (360,0.4)
        (420,0)
        };  
        \addplot[color=blue3,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,31)
        (300,53)
        (360,16)
        (420,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=blue4,style={line width=1pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,29)
        (300,55)
        (360,16)
        (420,0)
        };        
        \end{axis}  
        \end{tikzpicture}  
        \caption{Longevity - Sortino}   
        \label{LongGraph7}  
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8.25cm} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Bonus Potential (bn)},
        ylabel={Frequency},     
        xmin=0, xmax=600,
        ymin=0, ymax=80,
        xtick={0,100, 200,300,400,500,600},
        ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
        xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,      
        legend pos=north west,
        legend style={font=\tiny}]
        \legend{-20\%, -10\%, 0\%*, +10\%, +20\%},
        \addplot[color=blue1, style={line width=0.7pt},smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,4)
        (300,29)
        (360,49)
        (420,18)
        (480,0)
        };       
        \addplot[color=blue2,style={line width=0.8pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,1)
        (300,27)
        (360,45)
        (420,26)
        (480,1)
        (540,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=green,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,9.7)
        (300,47.8)
        (360,41.4)
        (420,1.1)
        (480,0)
        };  
        \addplot[color=blue3,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,1)
        (300,34)
        (360,48)
        (420,17)
        (480,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=blue4,style={line width=1pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
        (180,0)
        (240,1)
        (300,33)
        (360,43)
        (420,23)
        (480,0)
        };        
        \end{axis}  
        \end{tikzpicture}   
        \caption{Longevity - Risk Longevity}   
        \label{LongGraph8} 
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) doesn't compile. Please complete it with example-images.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I edited the post and added the entire code, I originally left out (collapsed) the graphs do to their length.

Answer (score 1):

You already found the solution by yourself (please post an answer instead of editing your question with the answer, even if your question probably is a duplicate), but since you loaded `subcaption` package, why aren't you using it?

I have also scaled your images, otherwise you got an Overfull hbox warning.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=raggedright,
    singlelinecheck=false,
    format=hang,
    font=small,labelfont=bf, skip=5pt} %default=10pt
\captionsetup[subfigure]{
    justification=raggedright,
    singlelinecheck=false,
    format=hang,
    belowskip=6pt,
    font=small,labelfont=bf, skip=5pt
}


%Color definitions
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0, 102, 0}
\definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{0, 125, 255}
\definecolor{blue2}{RGB}{0, 102, 204}
\definecolor{blue3}{RGB}{0, 76, 153}
\definecolor{blue4}{RGB}{0, 51, 102}

\begin{document}
    \section{Bonus Potential - Side by Side}
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\linewidth} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7] 
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Bonus Potential (bn)},
        ylabel={Frequency},     
        xmin=0, xmax=600,
        ymin=0, ymax=80,
        xtick={0,100, 200,300,400,500,600},
        ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
        xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,      
        legend pos=north west,
        legend style={font=\tiny}]
        \legend{-20\%, -10\%, 0\%*, +10\%, +20\%},
        \addplot[color=blue1, style={line width=0.7pt},smooth]
        coordinates {
            (120,0)
            (180,0)
            (240,39)
            (300,55)
            (360,6)
            (420,0)
        };       
        \addplot[color=blue2,style={line width=0.8pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (120,0)
            (180,1)
            (240,30)
            (300,59)
            (360,9)
            (420,1)
            (480,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=green,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (120,0)
            (180,5.8)
            (240,59.8)
            (300,34.2)
            (360,0.2)
            (420,0)
        };  
        \addplot[color=blue3,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (120,0)
            (180,1)
            (240,31)
            (300,62)
            (360,6)
            (420,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=blue4,style={line width=1pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (120,0)
            (180,1)
            (240,34)
            (300,52)
            (360,13)
            (420,0)
        };        
        \end{axis}  
        \end{tikzpicture}   
        \caption{Minimum Variance\label{Longminvar}}    
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\linewidth} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7] 
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Bonus Potential (bn)},
        ylabel={Frequency},     
        xmin=0, xmax=600,
        ymin=0, ymax=80,
        xtick={0,100, 200,300,400,500,600},
        ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
        xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,      
        legend pos=north west,
        legend style={font=\tiny}]
        \legend{-20\%, -10\%, 0\%*, +10\%, +20\%},
        \addplot[color=blue1, style={line width=0.7pt},smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,4)
            (300,35)
            (360,51)
            (420,10)
            (480,0)
        };       
        \addplot[color=blue2,style={line width=0.8pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,1)
            (300,31)
            (360,49)
            (420,18)
            (480,1)
            (540,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=green,style={line width=1pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,10.5)
            (300,56.4)
            (360,32.5)
            (420,0.6)
            (480,0)
        };  
        \addplot[color=blue3,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,31)
            (300,53)
            (360,16)
            (420,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=blue4,style={line width=1pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,1)
            (300,33)
            (360,43)
            (420,23)
            (480,0)
        };        
        \end{axis}  
        \end{tikzpicture}   
        \caption{Tangency Portfolio\label{Longtangport}}    
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\linewidth}  
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7] 
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Bonus Potential (bn)},
        ylabel={Frequency},     
        xmin=0, xmax=600,
        ymin=0, ymax=80,
        xtick={0,100, 200,300,400,500,600},
        ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
        xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,      
        legend pos=north west,
        legend style={font=\tiny}]
        \legend{-20\%, -10\%, 0\%*, +10\%, +20\%},
        \addplot[color=blue1, style={line width=0.7pt},smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,31)
            (300,53)
            (360,16)
            (420,0)
        };       
        \addplot[color=blue2,style={line width=0.8pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,37)
            (300,45)
            (360,17)
            (420,1)
            (480,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=green,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (120,0)
            (180,3.3)
            (240,50)
            (300,46.3)
            (360,0.4)
            (420,0)
        };  
        \addplot[color=blue3,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,31)
            (300,53)
            (360,16)
            (420,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=blue4,style={line width=1pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,29)
            (300,55)
            (360,16)
            (420,0)
        };        
        \end{axis}  
        \end{tikzpicture}  
        \caption{Sortino\label{Longsort}}     
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\linewidth} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7] 
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Bonus Potential (bn)},
        ylabel={Frequency},     
        xmin=0, xmax=600,
        ymin=0, ymax=80,
        xtick={0,100, 200,300,400,500,600},
        ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80},
        xtick pos=bottom,ytick pos=left,      
        legend pos=north west,
        legend style={font=\tiny}]
        \legend{-20\%, -10\%, 0\%*, +10\%, +20\%},
        \addplot[color=blue1, style={line width=0.7pt},smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,4)
            (300,29)
            (360,49)
            (420,18)
            (480,0)
        };       
        \addplot[color=blue2,style={line width=0.8pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,1)
            (300,27)
            (360,45)
            (420,26)
            (480,1)
            (540,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=green,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,9.7)
            (300,47.8)
            (360,41.4)
            (420,1.1)
            (480,0)
        };  
        \addplot[color=blue3,style={line width=0.9pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,1)
            (300,34)
            (360,48)
            (420,17)
            (480,0)
        };   
        \addplot[color=blue4,style={line width=1pt}, smooth]
        coordinates {
            (180,0)
            (240,1)
            (300,33)
            (360,43)
            (420,23)
            (480,0)
        };        
        \end{axis}  
        \end{tikzpicture}   
        \caption{Risk Longevity\label{Longrisk}}    
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Longevity\label{Long}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]